# Как настроить slick слайдер?

Tags: javascript, jquery, веб-программирование, вёрстка

Сделал на slick самый обычный, хорошо работающий слайдер. А теперь просят еще дополнительно сделать чтобы по клику на первый слайд (у которого **data-slick-index="0"**, и класс **slick-current**) делалась смена слайдов.

По умолчанию ведь прокрутка происходит по клику на все видимые слайды кроме первого (текущего).

```
$('.slider-small').slick({
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    asNavFor: '.slider-big',
    dots: false,
    centerMode: false,
    focusOnSelect: true,

});
```

Comment: Можете дать примерный код всего слайдера? Что бы здесь в `snippet` заработало?

Comment: Вопрос про Slider Syncing? А на что должен меняться слайд при клике на первый?

Comment: @РашенБеар Беар при клике на первый слайд должна просто делаться обычная смена слайдеров, и все, так же, как это происходит по клику на все остальные слайдеры

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я правильно понял ваш вопрос то надо просто для этого задать параметр

> infinite: true

В вашем коде будет:

```
$('.slider-small').slick({
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    infinite: true,
    asNavFor: '.slider-big',
    dots: false,
    centerMode: false,
    focusOnSelect: true,

});
```

А вот [тут](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) можете увидеть разные примеры `slick slider` и все параметры которые можно задать при инициализации слайдера.

Comment: Не совсем, infinite: true просто включает цикличную прокрутку. А мне нужно сделать чтобы по клику на все слайдеры (в том числе и текущий, у которого класс slick-current) делалась прокрутка сладеров.

Comment: @SergeyKonovalenko Вы хотите сказать кликнув на сами картинки?

Comment: Ну да, по клику на самих картинках

Comment: @SergeyKonovalenko Я как то не знаю такой дефолтной опции, хоть и не буть `current`, а перетащив можно